# Anaconda Problem with Capitalized PyPI Packages

Tags: python, anaconda, pypi

The environment I'm in requires anaconda, but I need some PyPI packages, so I'm trying to use anaconda's `conda skeleton pypi` functionality to make anaconda recipes and install them automatically. However, this seems to fail whenever the PyPI package name contains a capital letter, e.g., `Logbook` and `Represent`. Is there a way to make anaconda handle this gracefully, without manually creating recipes for each offending package?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/pypa/conveyor/issues/6.

Answer (score 0):

once you are in your conda environment you can use pip to install PyPi packages, using:

```
pip install package
```

you may need to `conda install pip` first.

So, for Represent it is `pip install represent`